# Implementing a structural equation model in a hybrid regression model with longitudinal data

Tags: r, stata, logistic-regression, hybrid, structural-equation-model

I am working on longitudinal data with three waves and have first utilized a hybrid probit regression model (within-between regression model). I have run the analyses in STATA using the following code:

```
xtprobit AdhLastWeekNewT m_povertyT d_povertyT /// 
BoyGirlT m_AgeT  d_AgeT m_RuralT  d_RuralT  m_HHSizeTotalT   d_HHSizeTotalT Timepoint  /// 
, re vce(cluster ID)
```

In a next step, I want to estimate a structural equation model to look at possible effect mediators. Does anyone know how I can implement a hybrid structural equation model in Stata or R? Are there any papers you are aware of that are using a similar approach?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! To avoid downvotes, it is generally encouraged to include a representative data example along with your code. Moreover, a more granular definition of "hybrid structural equation model" would be useful in eliciting an answer.

Comment: Having said that, this article may be of help: (https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/1536867X1301300105)

Comment: Thanks! The data is in long format, i.e. three lines per individual, representing three survey waves, for each variable. I have 933 participants per wave and thus a balanced sample. I followed these references for the main analyses, testing the effect of household poverty an adherence to HIV medication:
https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0110257
https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/political-science-research-and-methods/article/explaining-fixed-effects-random-effects-modeling-of-timeseries-crosssectional-and-panel-data/0334A27557D15848549120FE8ECD8D63

Comment: In this next step I would now like to look at the mechanisms behind the effect and implement a SEM using the same regression specification as in the main outcomes analyses

Comment: I suggest taking a look as the `gsem` command (https://www.stata.com/features/overview/generalized-sem/). See [this presentation](https://www.stata.com/meeting/germany14/abstracts/materials/de14_drukker_gsem.pdf) for it's implementation for panel data.